# Angular4 Injecting Http Is Undefined

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I am building this custom service for calling a Mock Backend to authenticate a user.

**Authentication Service :**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let user = response.json();
                if (user && user.token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }
            });
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }
}
```

**I inject this service into my login component and use it like this :**

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AlertService } from './../_services/alert.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from './../_services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'aa-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {};
  loading = false;
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
              private alertService: AlertService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authenticationService.logout();
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
  }

  login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
          },
          error => {
            this.alertService.error(error);
            this.loading = false;
          });
  }

}
```

**And my app.module looks like this:**

```
import { BaseRequestOptions, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { fakeBackendFactory, fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers/mock-backend.service';

import { AlertComponent } from './_directives/alert.component';
import { AlertService } from './_services/alert.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
import { AuthenticationService } from './_services/authentication.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MockBackend } from "@angular/http/testing";
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AlertComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, 
              AuthenticationService,
              AlertService,
              MockBackend,
              BaseRequestOptions,
              fakeBackendProvider],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Everything is imported in the module and well injected through the components. Still, when I call the login function of Authentication.service i get **this error**:

> LoginComponent.html:3 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
>       at AuthenticationService.webpackJsonp.86.AuthenticationService.login (authentication.service.ts:14)
>       at LoginComponent.webpackJsonp.88.LoginComponent.login (login.component.ts:28)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginComponent.html:3)
>       at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11826)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13041)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:12629)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8777)
>       at core.es5.js:10654
>       at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.es5.js:3840)
>       at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:236)

I even tried to inject my service with **@Inject(Http) private http** in authentication.service's constructor and I had the same error. What am I missing ?

Comment: Could you try and recreate this issue in a Plunker? :)

Comment: I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: Plunker has ready template, here, I started one for you :) http://plnkr.co/edit/TTjvv8ivEilRV9rKg80v